# Using angularjs filter in html attribute

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

Im trying to use a angularjs filter inside a html attribute:

Example:

```
<div heading="test | filtername"></div>
```

But this is not working.

if I do like this it workes fine:

```
<div>{{"test" | filtername}}</div>
```

can anyone explain what im doing wrong???

Comment: Post `heading` directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
<div heading="{{'test' | filtername}}"></div>
```